# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined infinte carousel

Tags: javascript

I implemented an infinite carousel on my site and I get the following error messages:

```
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined [line 58]
```

This is the site: http://www.dwmu.co.uk/test.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The problem is that there are apparently elements being passed in to the carousel initialization that have no "src" attribute.

Comment: A `<br>` element to be precise - not sure why.

Comment: ... it might be that it's paying attention to those `<br>` elements in your HTML, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plugin passes in *all* the elements in your container, and you have `<br>` elements between your images.  Try just getting rid of those.

*edit* — looking at the plugin source that definitely seems to be the case.

Comment: @user1096057: You can upvote and accept helpful questions and answers by clicking on the arrows and checkmarks. This helps organize the site and also gives some points to those involved.